# Convert Object with hasmap to XML using Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have an object containing just one hasmap type property.

```
public class Application {

    private Map<String,Object> map2;

    public Map<String, Object> getMap2() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map2);
    }

    public void setMap2(Map<String, Object> map2) {
        this.map2 = map2;
    }
}
```

And I try to generate an XML with Jackson :

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");

XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.configure( ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true );
System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(app));
```

The result is :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Application>
    <Map2>
        <key1>value1</key1>
        <key2>value2</key2>
    </Map2>
</Application>
```

But I would like to have only :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Application>
    <key1>value1</key1>
    <key2>value2</key2>
</Application>
```

How can I remove the Map2 element ?

Answer (score 3):

Use HashMap instead of the whole class. Like

```
public class AppDao {

    private Map<String,Object> Application;

    public Map<String, Object> getMap2() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map2);
    }

    public void setMap2(Map<String, Object> Application) {
    this.Application = Application;
    }
    public Map<String,Object> getMap2(){
        return Application;
    }
}
```

Now use the hashmap to generate XML

```
xmlMapper.configure( ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true );
System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(app.getMap2()));
```

Comment: I have already tried this solution. If I use HashMap instead of the whole object I obtain : <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><HashMap><key1>value1</key1><key2>value2</key2></HashMap>. So how can I just  rename HashMap to Application ?

Comment: Well, I created a new class Application that extends the HashMap class. And now it's ok. But the solution is not really "clean" !

Comment: @gduh What you're asking for is not really "clean"

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use `@JsonAnyGetter` annotation above `getMap2()`. Yep it's json annotation, but you have to use it for both xml and json https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml#additional-annotations

```
public static class Application {

    private Map<String,Object> map2;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getMap2() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map2);
    }

    public void setMap2(Map<String, Object> map2) {
        this.map2 = map2;
    }

    // if you need deserialization
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setMap2(String key, Object value) {
        map2.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

2-nd Option (if you can change your structure) is to use

```
public static class Application extends HashMap<String,Object> {}

// or if you want to change map class name:
@JsonRootName("Application")
public static class MyMap  extends HashMap<String,Object>{}
```